The VBA Set command is suddenly throwing up an error
I have several macros that I have used for years over various versions of Project and various versions of Windows. My current configuration is Windows version: 10.0.19045 Build 19045. I also have Office version: 2405 (Build 17628.20110 CTR) and Project 2019 Pro, same version as Office.
Today I tried running one of those macros on a test file and I immediately got this compile error

The declarations for my macros is typically this:
Option Explicit
Public Const ver = " 1.1"
Public xl As Excel.Application
Public WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
Public xlRange As Range
Public r As Resource
Public a As Assignment
Public TSV1 As TimeScaleValues

Later in the macro I open an instance of Excel using this construct:
'set up an new instance of Excel, or if Excel is not running, start it
On Error Resume Next
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Excel application is not available on this workstation" _
            & vbCr & "Install Excel or check network connection", vbCritical, _
            "Project Data Export - Fatal Error"
        FilterApply Name:="all tasks"
        Set xl = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0     'clear error function
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0

I have references set for the required Object libraries (i.e. Project, Office, Excel).
Thinking perhaps there was an issue related to the previous version of Office (version 2404 installed on May 14), I updated to the current version. This error still presents. Has anyone experienced this error or have suggestions for troubleshooting?

See this post for possible solutions.

braX, nope, the xl variable is only declared once as a public variable for the module which has 5 procedures, one public, the other 4 private routines

Rachel, Thanks for the reference. I'm surprised it didn't show up in the offering of similar questions when I typed my post, or maybe it did but I didn't catch it. At any rate, I used one of the possible solutions (i.e. re-ordering my references) and that did the trick. I clicked the up arrow but is there another way to recognize you for basically answering my question?

Glad to hear it solved your problem! Probably this question should be closed as a duplicate and posting my link as an answer isn't appropriate, so we can leave it as-is.
